# Typescript Assign custom object to any object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Trying to sort table data by using following the code https://github.com/chuvikovd/multi-column-sort, but how can I pass the custom object to the `SortArray[T]` object.

My custom object is like

```
const obj = [{parameter:'firstname', direction: 'ASC'},{parameter:'lastname', direction: 'DESC'}]
```

How can I convert `obj` to an array like `[['firstname':'ASC'],'lastname':'DESC']`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/chuvikovd/multi-column-sort#api),

> `sortArrayOrObject` **array** or **object** Array of tuples or object defining columns to be sorted by, order and direction e.g. `[['name', 'ASC'], ['city', 'DESC']]` or `{ name: 'ASC', city: 'DESC' }`.

You can transform the input array into an array of tuples using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const arr = [{ parameter: 'firstname', direction: 'ASC' }, { parameter: 'lastname', direction: 'DESC' }]

const result = arr.map((item) => [item.parameter, item.direction])

console.log(result)
```

Or you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform the input array into an object.

```js
const arr = [{ parameter: 'firstname', direction: 'ASC' }, { parameter: 'lastname', direction: 'DESC' }]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  ...acc,
  [item.parameter]: item.direction,
}), {})

console.log(result)
```